# Upload duplicate files using CMIS API

Tags: alfresco

I want to upload the two file having the same name into Alfresco Repository (I am able to do it into Documentum) but I am getting below exception 
Can somebody tell me how can I achieve it as it is my business use case in which the user can upload the document having the same name? Please note that the same is working as expected in the Documentum.

```
[2/12/20 16:43:03:554 IST] 00000040 SystemErr     R org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisContentAlreadyExistsException: An object with this name already exists: 01120277 File or folder Book_295_12.xlsx already exists
[2/12/20 16:43:03:555 IST] 00000040 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:506)
```

Comment: Alfresco doesn't allow duplicate names. It does allow duplicate titles. It also lets you version one node to store two different versions. I think you need to change your requirements

Comment: as @Gagravarr said alfresco does not allow duplicate files, one thing you can do is as OOTB Upload webscript  renames your file appending "- Counter" increasing the counter whenever the exception is caught. you can replicate the same in your code

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should override your contentModel.xml:

```
<type name="cm:folder">
    <title>Folder</title>
    <parent>cm:cmobject</parent>
    <archive>true</archive>
    <properties/>
    <associations>
        <child-association name="cm:contains">
            <source>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
            </source>
            <target>
                <class>sys:base</class>
                <mandatory enforced="false">false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
            </target>
            <duplicate>false</duplicate>
            <propagateTimestamps>true</propagateTimestamps>
        </child-association>
    </associations>
    <overrides/>
    <mandatory-aspects/>
</type>
```

As you can see there is **duplicate** param in child-association with "false" value. You should change it to "true"

Comment: We were facing many issues after editing the duplicate param in the content model.xml. Below issues was encountered by us (1) We were not able to see the document in the repository (folder) which was created after this change (changes in contentmodel.xml). I mean to say that we have updated the contentmodel.xml file and after that we have created a new folder in the Alfresco repository but we seen that the document was not visible even after successfully upload.

Answer (score 0):

I thing is not good idea duplicate child-association. Is different child-association as a name of property.

If you need a second name, why not adding this property in other type or aspect?

For example:

```
        <type name="mycm:mytype">
            <title>Test</title>
            <parent>cm:content</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="mycm:name">
                    <title>Common name</title>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </type>
```

Now, you can have documents with a same name with mycm:name and you can assigned timestamp to cm:name.